# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT (Retrofit 2)

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java

I get such an error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT`, when receive data from server. What can cause such an error? And how to fix it?

JSON which I receive from server:

```
{
  "group": [
    {
      "name": "Group1",
      "description": "Test Group 1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Group2",
      "description": "Group Name Updated"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is API interface:

```
@GET("groups")
    Observable <List<Group>> getAllGroups(@Header("Authorization") String auth,
                                   @Header("Content-type") String contentType,
                                   @Header("Accept") String accept
                                  );
```

Method where I receive data:

```
private void getAllGroups() {
    String credentials = "admin" + ":" + "admin";
    final String basic =
            "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
    String contentType = "application/json";
    String accept = "application/json";
    Subscription subscription = App.service.getAllGroups(basic, contentType, accept)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(groups -> {
                groupList.addAll(groups);
            }, throwable -> {
                Log.e("All group error", String.valueOf(throwable));
            });

    addSubscription(subscription);
}
```

Class Group:

```
public class Group {

    private String name;
    private String description;

    public Group(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of Observable <List<Group>> getAllGroups use Observable Group getAllGroups as the return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added class Groups:

```
public class Groups {

    @SerializedName("group")
    List<Group> group;
}
```

and changed code in API interface to:

```
 @GET("groups")
    Observable <Groups> getAllGroups(@Header("Authorization") String auth,
                                   @Header("Content-type") String contentType,
                                   @Header("Accept") String accept
                                  );
```

And after that app starts work without errors.